# Algorithm to draw uniform distributed points within an n-dimensional hypercube

Tags: geometry

As stated in the question, I'm looking for a way to generate uniformly distributed points inside n-dimensional unit cube. For the surface of the sphere, I can find some obvious solution but cannot find for this case. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "uniformly distributed"? It sounds like you would just take each coordinate to be a uniformly distributed random variable on $[0,1]$ so pick $n$ of them and you're set.  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Hi Robert, what I mean for that is like I want to generate points with normal distribution. The output is a n-by-k matrix with n points, each point is k-dimensional

Comment: Normal distributions go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. You said you want values inside the unit $n$-cube.  Do you mean to discard points that fall outside of it?  And is the center of the distribution the center of the cube, or a corner?

Comment: Oh sorry, my fault, it should be uniform distribution of points inside the cube, not normal distribution.

Comment: Evenly distributing points on a sphere is notoriously difficult problem even for $S^2$. See  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/9859/589

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Hi Robert, I think your suggestion is correct. However, I have a question about this. When I try to generate coordinate, what should I do with the point outside of the range [0,1]?

Comment: If you want a uniform distribution in an $n$-cube, just generate uniform random numbers on $[0,1]$, which is the base case for computer random number generators anyway.  Each one can be a coordinate of your desired point.  You won't have any numbers out of range to throw away that way, like you would if you used normal distribution.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor oh I got it, thank you so much. What made me confused is that I did the case of points on an n-sphere, which I have to generate normal distribution, but in this case, just use uniform distribution.